# How do I add "health" HEAD request in Azure function based on python?

Tags: python, http, azure-functions, serverless

I am using the Azure function HTTP trigger for a serverless python function.
Azure function has one endpoint (http://localhost:7071/api/func_name?param1=value1).
For health check, I am going to add another endpoint (as HEAD request).
Maybe this endpoint can be formed as :
http://localhost:7071/api/func_name/health.
How do I add this endpoint in Azure function?
That would be appreciated about any advice.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this requirement, you can create another function endpoint(create another httptrigger) and then add a `route` property(`"route":"func_name/health"`) in its `function.json` like below screenshot:

[image]

Then you can request the new function endpoint with url `http://localhost:7071/api/func_name/health`